# Potential race condition in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, race-condition

Given User and Transaction models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many     :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The problem arise with an API called too frequently:

```
def trx
  User.transaction do

    user       = User.where(id: @data.user.id).lock(true).first
    trx_number = user.transactions.count + 1

    # some work

    user.transactions.create(...)

    change_balance = ...

    user.balance = user.balance.to_f + change_balance.to_f

    inform_user = user.has_valid_informee

    if !result && inform_user
      inform_user.balance     = inform_user.aff_balance.to_f + @amount.to_f
      inform_user.save!
    end

    user.save!
  end

end
```

First I've got a race condition with updating user balance using just `@data.user`, sometimes new request finish before previous thus we lost some data. Instead I started requesting lock on that user.

Next race condition was with counting total transactions, and as I see it now we will have another RC with inform_user.

So the question is am I doing smth wrong? Is it a good way to rewrite updating balance of inform_user with:

```
    inform_user.with_lock do
      inform_user.balance     = inform_user.aff_balance.to_f + @amount.to_f
    end
```

And another question, is it a good way to use nesting locks, for example when I need to update relation models while updating a parent one?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the database directly by adding/subtracting based on what the database has (not what your Rails model currently has).  Take a look at `update_counters`.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update_counters

```
# For the Post with id of 5, decrement the comment_count by 1, and
# increment the action_count by 1
Post.update_counters 5, comment_count: -1, action_count: 1
# Executes the following SQL:
# UPDATE posts
#    SET comment_count = COALESCE(comment_count, 0) - 1,
#        action_count = COALESCE(action_count, 0) + 1
#  WHERE id = 5
```

Comment: Thank you for this advice, is it fine to use update_counters for updating user balances instead of Model.transaction, because Rails API suggests using simple transaction which doesn't work with complex models. Also what is the best way to lock model when I create or update an association on it?